# block google to search your admin section

Tags: admin, google-search

How to block google to show our website admin section in search result while searching in google?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your admin section should be password protected so google bot should not be able to progress more than login page.

If you want to disable even that you can use **robots.txt** to disallow access to admin section. This is an example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin
```

Check this [link](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt) to learn about robots.txt:

Answer (score 0):

You can use a robots.txt file to regulate where they will search if it is publicly accessible. That said, why is your admin section publicly accessible? Also, this will only work with companies like google who follow the robots.txt rules, an unscrupulous company might not.

[Google's info about robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt)
[Wikipedia on robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)